# Laravel 5.2 no directory for custom exceptions?

Tags: laravel-5

I am developing a project with laravel 5.2. I have a question, that is I found no directory for my own custom exceptions. So should I create a new directory or put in an existing directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see `app\Exceptions` directory? 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/structure#the-app-directory

> The `Exceptions` directory contains your application's exception handler and is also a good place to stick any exceptions thrown by your application.